# regexp which matches all tokens independent of order

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have a quick (and hopefully simple) question about regexps. I'm trying to think of a regexp which matches all of a set of tokens irrespective of order.

So for example I have a file with the names of the US states thus

```
Abbreviation:State name:Capital:Became a state
AL:Alabama:Montgomery:December 14, 1819
AK:Alaska:Juneau:January 3, 1959
AZ:Arizona:Phoenix:February 14, 1912
...
WI:Wisconsin:Madison:May 29, 1848
WY:Wyoming:Cheyenne:July 10, 1890
```

Say I wanted to find all states which had the letters "A", "R" and "N" in their names (case insensitive).

I could do a

```
$ cut -d: -f2 states.txt | tail -n +2 | grep -i a | grep -i r | grep -i n
```

which sure enough produces

```
Arizona
Arkansas
California
Maryland
Nebraska
New Hampshire
North Carolina
North Dakota
Rhode Island
South Carolina
Virginia
West Virginia
```

Is there any way of matching all three letters if they occur in any order using a single regexp?

Comment: you mean the names must contain above three letters?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Yes. Match stuff containing all tokens in any order. I don't think it's possible with a single regexp, but they can do such amazing things it wouldn't surprise me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `awk`:

```
$ awk '/a|A/ && /R|r/ && /N|n/' file
Arizona
Arkansas
California
Maryland
Nebraska
New Hampshire
North Carolina
North Dakota
Rhode Island
South Carolina
Virginia
West Virginia
```

With `gawk`, you can use [IGNORECASE](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Case_002dsensitivity.html#index-gawk_002c-IGNORECASE-variable-in):

```
gawk '/a/ && /r/ && /n/' IGNORECASE=1 file
```

Answer (score 2):

The `grep` command does not have a proper AND operator so you have to get creative when trying to solve problems such as this one. You can do, as you've elected to do and chain multiple `grep`'s together. But you can also do something like this:

```
$ echo -e "arie\narin" | grep -i '[arn].*[arn].*[arn]'
arin
```

This will match any strings that contains a combination of a,r, or n, and it must contain 3 occurrences of characters from this set.

#### Words with spaces

To deal with spaces you can adapt the above regex like so:

```
$ echo -e "arie\narin\nar nie" | \
    grep -i '[arn][[:alpha:]]*[arn][[:alpha:]]*[arn]'
arin
```

Here instead of accepting any type of character in between our `[arn]` blocks we're being more selective, only taking characters from the `[[:alpha:]]` set. Also we're telling `grep` that we want `*`, i.e. zero or more of these characters in between.

Comment: good answer ! thanks ! but what about space ? or upercases ?

Comment: @sim: Thanks for that. Unfortunately it doesn't work as it matches "a" OR "r" OR "n", and so matches Alabama, Alsaka... whereas I want "a" AND "r" AND "n" (I could just use the regexp '[arn].*?{3,}' I suppose.

Comment: This also matches `aaa` or `aar`...

Answer (score 0):

```
cut -d: -f2 states.txt | tail -n +2 | egrep -i  '[arn].*[arn].*[arn]'
```

Comment: I'm sorry, i only think to about capital letter, i updated.

Answer (score 0):

Well one option is `sed` although this may be substantially slower than the `grep` alternative

```
cut -d: -f2 states.txt | tail -n +2 |  sed -n -e '/a/I{/r/I{/n/Ip}}'
Arizona
Arkansas
California
Maryland
Nebraska
New Hampshire
North Carolina
North Dakota
Rhode Island
South Carolina
Virginia
West Virginia
```

Comment: I'm not religious about using grep, although it tends to be the regexp tool that's at the top of the toolbox. Nor does speed matter: it's an arbitrary exercise (prompted by a question on a UK TV quiz show!) where I was hoping to improve my imperfect knowledge of the various tools available. Thanks for the steer.